# How to scroll to an element in TableView in Appium (Java)?

Tags: java, ios, automated-tests, appium

I have to scroll down to a element and then tap this element.
I have tried using TouchAction, but it does not work.

P.S I'm new to Appium

Comment: Welcome to SO @Nischay Gulati!  You will want to include more information (like an explanation of exactly what 'not working' means and, possibly, a code sample) to increase your chance of getting helpful responses.  Please see [the SO how to ask guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`driver.ScrollTo("String")`; and then click on that element.

Comment: I'am using a MobileDriver, it does not have any method ScrollTo , what version would have that ?

Comment: rectified that by using AppiumDriver now

Comment: As i had a TableView I used driver.swipe; but nothing happens .Is this functionality broken ?